# как расположить кнопки в layout в коде по правому краю одну под другой

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Здравствуйте, как я могу выровнять выровнять кнопки по правой стороне, одну под другой из кода, в классе ButtonsLayout?

```
public class Activity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView glView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);  
            // glView здесь куча параметров для glView  которые по идее не имеют отношения к вопросу
            this.setContentView(glView);    
            this.addContentView(new ButtonsLayout(this), new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));    
        }        
    }
```

Вот класс ButtonsLayout .

```
public class ButtonsLayout extends LinearLayout {

            public ButtonsLayout(Context context) {

                super(context);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

                Button btn1 = new Button(context);
                btn1.setText("Button1");
                addView(btn1, rightGravityParams);


                Button btn2 = new Button(context);
                btn2.setText("Button2");
                addView(btn2, rightGravityParams);    
               }
    }
```

Мне нужно чтобы кнопки были по правому краю и одна под другой.  А у меня получается, что они находятся слева и на одной строке.

Comment: Зачем вы хотите это сделать программно, а не через xml layout?

Comment: Можно и через XML, но через XML у меня не получилось добавить методом addContentView() , зато получилось программно.
Если есть вариант решения, где класс загружает XML layout, а потом вставляется посредством addContentView() , то это было бы даже лучше.

Comment: `LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View tmpView;
tmpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_layout, null);
getWindow().addContentView(tmpView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));`

Comment: Я создал test.xml в папке layout.  
Но после поппытки его получить :    View tmpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);     
Вылетает ошибка:  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040027

Comment: Куда смотрит `R.layout.test`? Такое ощущение ось не видит `test.xml`

Comment: @fantastic, проверьте импорты, потому что  IDE могла импортировать не тот класс. У вас должен импортироваться класс `R` из вашего пакета, т.е. должна присутствовать такая строка `import имя_вашего_пакета.R;`.

Comment: Активити которая запрашивает test.xml  лежит в таком пакете :  com.organization.superproject.myactivity;   
А R импортирован отсюда  import com.simplesolution.superproject.R;  
то есть на один пакет "выше" . 
если я тыкаю contrl + клик. по R переменной, то я перехожу в IDE на test.xml файл.